# For $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}\setminus\{ 0\}$, prove that $\mathbb{Q}/\langle x \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Q}/ \langle y \rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

For $x$, $y$ nonzero rationals, I need to prove that $\mathbb{Q}/\langle x \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Q}/ \langle y \rangle$.

To do this, I was thinking about using the **Third Isomorphism Theorem**:

> Let $M, N \trianglelefteq G$ and $M \leq N$. Then, $(G/M)/(N/M)\simeq G/N$.

However, this would only make sense if $\langle y \rangle$ was a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$. I know it is cyclic, and hence abelian, but is it also normal?

Then, I could let $M = e_{G}$ (the identity element in $G$), but then $\langle x \rangle = N/M = N/e = N = \langle y \rangle$, which doesn't make any sense.

So, suffice it to say, I am at a loss as to how to prove this result! :(

Could somebody please help me figure out how to prove this? Thank you.

Comment: There are so many things here you really need to take another look at. Abelian subgroups need not be normal (subgroups of abelian groups are normal might be what you had in mind). Cyclic groups *are* however abelian.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft you're right, I just realized (lack of sleep will do that to a person). So, I just edited that part of the question. I wonder then, if the 3rd Isomorphism Theorem is not the way to go. And if not, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @JessyCat: In a commutative group, every subgroup is normal. Since $\Bbb Q$ is commutative, it follows that you need not worry about normality in this problem.

Comment: @AlexM. it still doesn't help me though, because if I apply the third isomorophism theorem, I still end up with $\langle x \rangle = \langle y \rangle$, which is weird.

Comment: @JessyCat: I don't think that this problem is about the 3rd isomorphism theorem. Pjotr5's answer is very good, provided that you supplement it with the missing details. Hint: show that $\Bbb Q / \langle 1 \rangle$ is $[0,1) \cap \Bbb Q$, with the group law given by $\frac p q + \frac r s = (ps + qr) \pmod {qs}$.

Comment: @AlexM. by "is" do you mean "is isomorphic to"?

Comment: Do you know the homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$? Can you find one that maps $\langle x\rangle$ to $\langle y\rangle$? Can you see it induces a homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}/\langle x\rangle\to\mathbb{Q}/\langle y\rangle$? Is it an isomorphism?

Comment: @AlexM. Presumably you mean $$\frac{p}{q}+\frac{r}{s}=\frac{ps+qr\bmod qs}{qs}. $$

Comment: @arctictern: Obviously, thank you. I can't edit my comment anymore, though, so I'll leave it as it is now.

Comment: @AlexM. how does that help me show that $f$ is a surjective.

Comment: @arctictern how does showing htat $\mathbb{Q}/\langle 1 \rangle$ is $[0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ show that the map is surjective?

Comment: Technically those aren't the same, the latter is a set of coset representatives for $\langle 1\rangle\le\Bbb Q$. Anyways, what map are you talking about?

Comment: @arctictern the one that Pjotr gives in his answer below.

Comment: @arctictern no that's to show it's a homomorphism. I want to show it's surjective.

Comment: Oh. Pick an arbitrary element in the codomain, and exhibit something that gets mapped to it.

Comment: @arctictern, so, $\frac{x}{a}$ is in the codomain. For every such $\frac{x}{a}$ there exists a $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ that maps to it. Is that it?

Comment: Well, I would say: pick $y+\langle 1\rangle\in\Bbb Q/\langle 1\rangle$, and notice $ay\in\Bbb Q$ gets mapped to it.

Comment: @arctictern Ted Shifrin made it sound way more complicated than that. I was just talking to him in the chat and he got impatient with me, I got mad at him for getting impatient with me, and then he basically told me to buzz off.

Comment: @JessyCat I just looked at the transcript. Don't feel bad, ideas like "killing" elements and "identifying" them are the high concept view of things that you want to work towards, but newcomers generally don't get this stuff naturally. You said you're a visual person and have a hard time understanding something unless you see it, so let's consider $\Bbb R/\langle a\rangle\cong\Bbb R/\langle b\rangle$ instead.

Comment: Both $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle$ on the number line look like a bunch of equally-spaced-apart points, but one will be more spread than the other depending on the relative sizes of $a$ and $b$. Is there something obvious we can do to $\Bbb R$ which maps $\langle a\rangle$ to $\langle b\rangle$? Here's another perspective: the intervals $[0,a)$ and $[0,b)$ (assuming $a,b$ are positive) are nice sets of coset representatives for $\Bbb R/\langle a\rangle$ and $\Bbb R/\langle b\rangle$ respectively. Is there anything we can do to $\Bbb R$ that stretches $[0,a)$ to $[0,b)$?

Comment: Yes, there is: we can scale all real numbers by a factor of $b/a$ (so that $a$ is stretched/shrunk to $b$). In fact, $$x+\langle a\rangle\mapsto \frac{b}{a}x+\langle b\rangle$$ is an isomorphism $\Bbb R/\langle a\rangle\to\Bbb R/\langle b\rangle$. If you want, you can think of this as $$x+\langle a\rangle\mapsto\frac{b}{a}\left(x+\langle a\rangle\right),$$ so the map is literally "multiplication by $b/a$." Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: @arctictern yes, it does. You're nice! :) It's not helpful when people expect you to be an expert and then when you're not, insult you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you look no further than the **first isomorphism theorem**.

Take some nonzero $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ and convince yourself of the fact that if we show that $\mathbb{Q}/\langle a \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}/\langle 1 \rangle$ we are done. Define the map $$f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\langle 1 \rangle,\quad x \mapsto \frac{1}{a} \cdot x$$ and do the following:

- Show that $f$ is an homomorphism.
- Show that $f$ is surjective.
- Show that $\ker{(f)} = \langle a \rangle$.
- Apply the first isomorphism theorem to find $\mathbb{Q}/\ker{(f)} \cong \text{im}{(f)}$.

Comment: This requires the OP to know how $\Bbb Q / \langle 1 \rangle$ looks like, wich is essentially the solution of the problem. In other words, how does the OP know that $\frac x a$ is an element of $\Bbb Q / \langle 1 \rangle$? Your proof is therefore circular.

Comment: @Pjotr5 is the reason why if we show $\mathbb{Q}\langle a \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Q}\langle 1 \rangle$ because we can obtain any $\langle b \rangle$ (where $b \in \mathbb{Q}$) from $\langle 1 \rangle$ by multiplying all the elements of $\langle 1 \rangle$ by $b$?

Comment: @AlexM. do you have a better solution?

Comment: @AlexM. I don't agree. I haven't given a proof but rather I've given a recipe that can be made into a rigorous proof. Since $\frac{x}{a}$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}$, it becomes an element of $\mathbb{Q}/\langle 1\rangle$ after reduction. What reduction exactly means is for the OP to figure out.

Comment: @Pjotr5: In this case I agree: this post is more like a study program for the OP to follow.

Comment: @JessyCat No, I was thinking more of the simple reason that if for all $x,y$ we find $$\mathbb{Q}/\langle x \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}/\langle 1 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}/\langle y \rangle$$ we can conclude immediately that $$\mathbb{Q}/\langle x \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}/\langle y \rangle.$$

Comment: @Pjotr5 by reduction do you mean as in  $\mathbb{Q}\langle 1 \rangle $ is the set of cosets $q \langle 1 \rangle$, where $q \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @JessyCat Exactly. For example $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{2}$ are different elements of $\mathbb{Q}$, but the same element in $\mathbb{Q}/\langle 1 \rangle$. When I write $\frac{x}{a} \in \mathbb{Q}/\langle 1 \rangle$ I abuse the notation a little bit, I should actually write the element $\frac{x}{a} + \langle 1 \rangle$ of $\mathbb{Q}/\langle 1 \rangle$.

Comment: @Pjotr5 I'm having some trouble showing that the map is surjective. Let $y \in \mathbb{Q}/\langle 1 \rangle$. Then, $y = q + \langle 1 \rangle$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Can any $q$ be written in the form $\frac{x}{a}$? I'm not sure how to show this. Can you provide more details for how to show that $f$ is surjective?

Comment: @AlexM. if you're around, perhaps you could answer my question? Pjotr5 has not been on here in 6 hours...

Comment: @arctictern Sorry to keep bugging you, buddy. But, do you have anything to say?

Comment: @JessyCat Yes, $q = \frac{a q}{a}$.